# Swift URLSession running asynchronously so it doesn't register in time for onAppear to add data to View

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous, swiftui, urlsession

I am trying to call an API and then display that data in my view in Swift. I can successfully make the API call and get the data back, but I am having trouble displaying this data. As seen in the below code, my load function moves on before it is done decoding the data and saving it in a self variable.

Here is the load function:

```
func loadRestaurant(completed:@escaping () -> ()) {
    print("loaded started")
    //print(self.restaurants)
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/restaurant/") else {
        print("api is down")
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("Basic a21jY2xlbm46ZGV4SVNkZXgzMTQ=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    print("request created")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
//
            if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Restaurant].self, from: data) {
                print("decoder run")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.restaurants = response
                    //print(self.restaurants)
                    queue.async {
                        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: Double.random(in: 0...2))
                        completed()
                    }
                }
                
                return
            } else {
                print("response decoding failed")
            }
            
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Here is how I am trying to display in in the view:

```
@State var restaurants = [Restaurant]()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
var body: some View {
    
    ForEach(restaurants, id: \.id) {item in
        HStack {

            Text(item.name)
            Spacer()

        }
    }.onAppear(perform: {
        print("before running function")
        loadRestaurant(completed: {
            print("restaurants: \(restaurants)")
            
        })
        
        print("after running function")
        
})
}
```

When I run the program, the order of the print statements goes like this:

before running function

loaded started

request created

after running function

decoder run

restaurants: *RESTAURANTS DATA*

As you can see, the decoder and the final display of the data (where it is saved to the self.restaurants variable) runs after the .onAppear finishes. So, there is no data to be loaded into the display. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I have tried to add a closure (see the completed() function), but it seems like there is no way to re-draw the view even after the closure function is run. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should create a class that conforms to `ObservableObject` and has the `restaurants` property as a `@Published` property and then move your download function to this class and let it assign the decoded result to the published property

Comment: If you can spare half an hour, you might want to learn about the recent async/ await functionalities in Swift, watching [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/). It can help you implementing your code the way you expect it to do.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried this and it still did the same thing. I am not sure if I am doing it right though. I created a class called `Load` that conforms to `ObservableObject`, and I set restaurants: `@Published var restaurants: [Restaurant]`. I also added the `loadRestaurant` function to the `Load` class. In the `.onAppear` function, I used an instance of the class, ran `loadRestaurant`, and set `self.restaurants = loadInstance.restaurants`. It still didn't work, do you have any ideas?

Comment: The behaviour looks ok, it's standard async operation flow: launch operation, update state when it finishes, SwiftUI automatically picks up the state change and redraws the view.  Maybe the `ForEach` has something to do with this? You can try with a `List`, and see of something changes.

Comment: You should not have a self.restaurants, instead you should directly use the loadInstance.restaurants in your view, `ForEach(loadInstance.restaurants,...`. What will happen is that once the download function is done and assigns the result to the published property the Load instance will tell the view that the published property has changed and the view will update itself. It is also important that the Load property is either set to be a StateObject or a ObservedObject. You should search for and read up on ObservableObject, there are plenty of articles on the subject.